Resultant $\mathrm{Res}_{x}(f(x), y - g(x))$ calculation and divisibility by $f$
I have learned the definition of the Resultant of two polynomials Resultant of two polynomials. In most places, it is defined over a field. Can we similarly define it for the general ring, for example, $R = \mathbb{Z}/(p^{k}\mathbb{Z})$, where $p$ is any prime and $k \in \mathbb{N}$?
Assume $f(x), g(x) \in R[x]$.  Suppose we define the function $\mathcal{R}(y) = \mathrm{Resultant}(f(x), y - g(x))$. Now, I think this function is valid because to compute this function, we need to calculate the determinant of the Sylvester matrix of $f(x), y - g(x)$ (assume $y$ like a constant).
My second question is: Can we prove that $f(x)$ divides $\mathcal{R}(g(x))$?
For example let $f(x) = f_0 + f_1 x + f_2 x^2, g(x) = g_{0} + g_{1}x$, then $~S = \begin{pmatrix}f_{0} & y - g_{0} & 0
\\f_{1} & - g_{1} & y - g_{0} \\f_{2} & 0 & - g_{1}  \end{pmatrix}$
Then $\mathcal{R}(y) = \det(S)$ and $\mathcal{R}(g_{0} + g_{1}x) \\= \det \begin{pmatrix}f_{0} & g_{1}x & 0
\\f_{1} & - g_{1} & g_{1}x \\f_{2} & 0 & - g_{1}  \end{pmatrix} \\= g_{1}^{2}(f_0 + f_1 x + f_2 x^2) \\= g_{1}^{2}f(x)$.
So $f(x)$ divides $\mathcal{R}(g(x))$, but $\mathcal{R}(g(x)) \neq 0$.
But I couldn't able to prove the general statement.

To answer the first part in your question, resultants can be defined over commutative rings. In fact it is often the case that one is interested in polynomials $R[x]$, where $R$ itself is a polynomial ring in some other indeterminate(s), with the aim of eliminating $x$. In that case one would be interested in the resultant over $R$.
In the Wikipedia article that you've linked, in the section Properties, you can see that a resultant is defined over a commutative ring, but some important properties like uniqueness are valid only for integral domains.
However, always check against a more "traditional" source, as I have previously found some issues with the properties listed in that wiki article that were swiftly corrected.
About your second question:
Let $z$ be an indeterminate independent of $x$ and $y$ and consider $f$ as a polynomial in $z$. Let $h$ be a polynomial in $z$ given by:
$$h(z) = \sum_{i=1}^k g_i x^i - \sum_{i=1}^k g_i z^i,$$
where $k$ is the degree of $g$. With this notation in mind, your matrix $\mathcal R$ is recovered as the Sylvester matrix of $f$ and $h$ with respect to $z$, that is $\mathcal R(g) = \operatorname{Res}_z(f,h)$.
Now $h$ factors nicely as $h(z)=(x-z)\sum_{i=1}^kg_i(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}z+\cdots+xz^{k-2}+z^{k-1})$. To simplify notation a bit, I'll write $h(z)=(x-z)H(x,z)$.
Using the multiplicative property of the resultant, we have
$$\operatorname{Res}_z(f,h) = \operatorname{Res}_z(f,(x-z)H(x,z))=\operatorname{Res}_z(f,x-z)\cdot \operatorname{Res}_z(f,H(x,z)).$$
The only thing that $\operatorname{Res}_z(f,x-z)$ is doing is "renaming" $f$ from a polynomial in $z$ to a polynomial in $x$, therefore
$$\operatorname{Res}_z(f,x-z)\cdot \operatorname{Res}_z(f,H(x,z))=f(x)\cdot \operatorname{Res}_z(f,H(x,z))$$
